# google foobar : 'please pass the coded messages'. What is the matter in my code?

Tags: python

I happend to see the google foobar challenges and

i'm struggling to solve a problem, 'please pass the coded messages'

When submiting my solution code, i get the response that one failing in 5 tests.

I really scrutinize my code, but i can't discover any error in mine.

--Problem--
You need to pass a message to the bunny workers, but to avoid detection, the code you agreed to use is... obscure, to say the least. The bunnies are given food on standard-issue plates that are stamped with the numbers 0-9 for easier sorting, and you need to combine sets of plates to create the numbers in the code. The signal that a number is part of the code is that it is divisible by 3. You can do smaller numbers like 15 and 45 easily, but bigger numbers like 144 and 414 are a little trickier. Write a program to help yourself quickly create large numbers for use in the code, given a limited number of plates to work with.

You have L, a list containing some digits (0 to 9). Write a function solution(L) which finds the largest number that can be made from some or all of these digits and is divisible by 3. If it is not possible to make such a number, return 0 as the solution. L will contain anywhere from 1 to 9 digits.  The same digit may appear multiple times in the list, but each element in the list may only be used once.

--Samples--

Input:
solution.solution([3, 1, 4, 1])
Output:
4311

Input:
solution.solution([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9])
Output:
94311

--My solution--

```
def jointer(l):
    res=0
    for i, v in enumerate(l):
        if v==0:
            res=res*10
        else:
            res+=v*10**i
    return res

def solution(L):
    L=sorted(L)
    ll=[]
    s=0 
    for i in L:
        ll.append(i%3)
        s+=i
    r=s%3
    if r==1:
        if 1 in ll:
            L.pop(ll.index(1))
        else:
            for _ in range(2):
                L.pop(ll.index(2))
    elif r==2:
        if 2 in ll:
            L.pop(ll.index(2))
        else:
            for _ in range(2):
                L.pop(ll.index(1))
    return jointer(L)
```

I'd like to ask you guys what is the problem in this code.

Thank you for your help in advence

Answer (score 0):

You need to be thinking in terms of permutations of the digits in the input list. Bear in mind that the challenge states that "some or all" of the values may be used. So you need to be looking at permutations from 1 to the length of the input list (inclusive).

There's probably a more efficient way to do this but:

```
from itertools import permutations

def solution(digits):
    _max = -1
    for r in range(1, len(digits)+1):
        for combo in permutations(digits, r=r):
            v = 0
            for n in combo:
                v = v * 10 + n
            if v % 3 == 0:
                _max = max(_max, v)
    return _max

print(solution([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]))
```

**Output:**

```
94311
```